# Kubernetes + calico + replicaSet

Tags: kubernetes, replicaset, calico

So I found myself in a pretty sticky situation. I'm trying to create a simple replicaSet, but unfortunately I ran into some problems with the calico.

I have 2 VM running on OracleVM. I have them configured to use enp0s8 interface. The IP of the master node is 192.168.56.2 and the worker node's ip is 192.168.56.3

Here is what I'm doing in Kubernetes. First I'm creating the kubernetes master node:

```
kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16 --apiserver-advertise-address=192.168.56.2
```

after successfuly initialzing I'm running:

```
export KUBECONFIG=/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf
```

Now I'm creating the POD network by running:

```
kubectl apply -f https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.11/manifests/calico.yaml
```

after that I'm joining from the worker node successfully. Whenever I start the replica with:

*** edit: I don't have to create the replicaset to obtain the same result of the calico-node creation getting stuck

```
kubectl create -f replicaset-definition.yml
```

in which the yml looks like this:

```
kind: ReplicaSet
metadata:
  name: myapp-replicaset
  labels:
    app: myapp
    type: front-end
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      name: myapp-pod
      labels:
        app: myapp
        type: front-end
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nginx-container
          image: nginx
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapp
```

I'm getting a new calico-node created which eventually will get stuck

```
calico-node-mcb5g                          0/1     Running   6          8m58s
calico-node-t9p5n                          1/1     Running   0          12m
```

If I run 
`kubectl logs -n kube-system calico-node-mcb5g -f` 
on it I get the following logs:

```
2020-03-18 14:45:40.585 [INFO][8] startup.go 275: Using NODENAME environment for node name
2020-03-18 14:45:40.585 [INFO][8] startup.go 287: Determined node name: kubenode1
2020-03-18 14:45:40.587 [INFO][8] k8s.go 228: Using Calico IPAM
2020-03-18 14:45:40.588 [INFO][8] startup.go 319: Checking datastore connection
2020-03-18 14:46:10.589 [INFO][8] startup.go 334: Hit error connecting to datastore - retry error=Get https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/nodes/foo: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout
2020-03-18 14:46:41.591 [INFO][8] startup.go 334: Hit error connecting to datastore - retry error=Get https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/nodes/foo: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout
```

I've tried to configure the calico.yml and added the following line in env:

```
- name: IP_AUTODETECTION_METHOD
  value: "interface=enp0s8"
```

but the result is still the same.

Thank you so much for reading this and if you have any advice I will be sooo grateful!!!

Comment: check if kube proxy pods are running and any error in kube-proxy pod logs

Comment: ok so here I check the proxy:
```
ps auxw | grep kube-proxy
root      7912  0.0  1.4 140108 28724 ?        Ssl  11:05   0:02 /usr/local/bin/kube-proxy --config=/var/lib/kube-proxy/config.conf --hostname-override=kubemaster
root     19601  0.0  0.0  21292   940 pts/8    S+   12:09   0:00 grep --color=auto kube-proxy
```

Comment: is there a firewall on node which is blocking traffic to 10.96.0.1:443

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so here it goes. What it seemed to be was that calico node crashed because the service CIDR and host CIDR overlaped.

If I initiate the master node with the CIDR changed as:

```
kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=20.96.0.0/12 --apiserver-advertise-address=192.168.56.2
```

works like a charm.

This helped a lot:
[Cluster Creation Successful but calico-node-xx pod is in CrashLoopBackOff Status](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/cluster-api-provider-ibmcloud/issues/153)